# Rhino mocks .Repeat.Any() not working for me

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I was having problems with a second call on a mock in my test run, so I moved the double calls into the test method. I have this:

```
RefBundle mockIRefBundle = mocks.StrictMock<IRefBundle>();

Expect.Call(mockIRefBundle.MaxTrackItems).Return( 6 ).Repeat.Any();

int q = mockIRefBundle.MaxTrackItems;
int z = mockIRefBundle.MaxTrackItems;
```

It fails when I make the second call to set "z" with an exception that implies the method was already called:

Error message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Previous method 
'IRefBundle.get_MaxTrackItems();
'requires a return value or an exception to throw..
```

and Stack

```
Rhino.Mocks.Impl.RecordMockState.AssertPreviousMethodIsClose()
Rhino.Mocks.Impl.RecordMockState.MethodCall(IInvocation invocation, 
...
```

The second call doesn't seem to honor the Repeat.Any()

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you have to use the new syntax:

```
RefBundle mockIRefBundle = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IRefBundle>();

mockIRefBundle.Expect(X => x.MaxTrackItems).Return(6).Repeat.Any();

int q = mockIRefBundle.MaxTrackItems;
int z = mockIRefBundle.MaxTrackItems;
```

or alternatively you need to call `ReplayAll()` before you start using your mocks:

```
RefBundle mockIRefBundle = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IRefBundle>();

mockIRefBundle.Expect(X => x.MaxTrackItems).Return(6).Repeat.Any();

mocks.ReplayAll();
int q = mockIRefBundle.MaxTrackItems;
int z = mockIRefBundle.MaxTrackItems;
```

Comment: Thanks - I find the Rhino docs to be very confusing, so I end up mixing and matching syntax. Can you recommend a good guide?

Comment: Hi @ddm, I don't really know any good guides myself :( Lots of practice + stackoverflow I would say.

Comment: Thanks @Grzenio - what would we do without SO :-)

Comment: @ddm, There's some guides posted up here if you still need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185021/rhino-mocks-good-tutorials/7682246#7682246